# R: expand sequence of binary values from two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, binary

I have a very complex dataset. But for simplification I am going to use this data. Let's assume we have this data, one column X showing numbers in different ranges and the other column is binary 0/1. I want to expand a sequence of binary 0/1 by 1. This will create new longer columns (newX, newbinary) form the original X and binary columns.

```
  X    binary
1 1    1
2 3    0
3 5    0
4 6    1
5 8    1
6 10   0
```

I want to expand X column here and put the binary value next to it. Something like,

```
   newX    newbinary
1   1       1
2   2       1
3   3       0
4   4       0
5   5       0
6   6       1
7   7       1
8   8       1
9   9       1
10  10      0
```

My attempts is this, First I created the new X column (expanded the X).

```
   newX <- seq(X[1], X[length])
```

Then, I used for loop to iterate through newX and then compare the value with X to check if it is equal to or less than the value. If newX[i] is not equal to X[i], then put the previous binary value, else put the binary[i].

```
    for (i in 1:newX[length])
  {
    newbinary= ifelse((newX != X)&(between(newX[i], X[i],X[j+1])), lag(binary), binary)
   }
```

But this is not working and give me this,

```
   newX    newbinary
  1 1         1
  2 2        NA
  3 3        NA
  4 4        NA
  5 5        NA
  6 6        NA
```

I don't really know how the newX column (longer one) will iterate through X (shorter one) and put the value correspondingly.

How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `tidyverse` approach creating a dataframe for the sequence, then use `left_join()` and finally `fill()` to complete the binary variable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
newdf <- data.frame(X=seq(min(df$X),max(df$X),by=1)) %>%
  left_join(df) %>%
  fill(binary)
```

Output:

```
    X binary
1   1      1
2   2      1
3   3      0
4   4      0
5   5      0
6   6      1
7   7      1
8   8      1
9   9      1
10 10      0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(X = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 10L), binary = c(1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thank you! This didn't work with my data. The original data is found here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65098710/r-expand-sequence-of-binary-values-from-a-time-column

Comment: This looks good for simple data maybe? I got this error, Error: `by` must be supplied when `x` and `y` have no common variables.

Comment: @AmalNasir Some typo in the `seq()`, try setting a value inside it!

Comment: Actually the problem is with left_joint(). seq() gives me the sequence I wanted.

Comment: Check the variables, must have the same name for joining!

Comment: It is working! I have never thought of joint. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% mutate(y = lead(X, default = max(X)+1), newX = map2(X,y-1,`:`)) %>% 
   unnest(newX) %>% mutate(newbinary = binary) %>% select(newX, newbinary)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
    newX newbinary
   <int>     <dbl>
 1     1         1
 2     2         1
 3     3         0
 4     4         0
 5     5         0
 6     6         1
 7     7         1
 8     8         1
 9     9         1
10    10         0
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 6 x 2
      X binary
  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1      1
2     3      0
3     5      0
4     6      1
5     8      1
6    10      0
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try this out. The original "complex" data is here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65098710/r-expand-sequence-of-binary-values-from-a-time-column

Comment: This gives me the same data I have. I am only able to see the first 10 lines and there are 522 more row, how can I view all the data here with a tibble? When I view df, this gives me the exact same data.

Comment: @AmalNasir, you probably need to separate the whole number and decimals and work with whole numbers using same logic as above.

Comment: I don't think I get this, unnest(newX). Can I get the new columns in another df?

Comment: @AmalNasir, so unnest is used to expand list columns.

Comment: I guess this is working but I see some duplicate values. Is there a way to remove the duplicate?

Comment: @AmalNasir, you can use distinct function to remove duplicates

Comment: After some modification, it worked. However, if I use your code, I got the output as tibble (The same output you put). If I View(df), I got the original data. How can I use the tibble as data frame for analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data frame shown reproducibly in the Note at the end the following one-linear uses `read.zoo` to convert it to a zoo object and converts that to a ts object expanding it at the same time.  Then it uses na.locf to fill in the NAs and fortify.zoo to convert it to a data.frame.  Set the names on the data frame to the original names.

```
library(zoo)
setNames(fortify.zoo(na.locf(as.ts(read.zoo(DF)))), names(DF))
```

giving:

```
    X binary
1   1      1
2   2      1
3   3      0
4   4      0
5   5      0
6   6      1
7   7      1
8   8      1
9   9      1
10 10      0
```

The above one-linear could alternately be written as a pipeline:

```
library(zoo)
library(magrittr)

DF %>%
  read.zoo %>%
  as.ts %>%
  na.locf %>%
  fortify.zoo %>%
  setNames(names(DF))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
  X    binary
1 1    1
2 3    0
3 5    0
4 6    1
5 8    1
6 10   0"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```